# Send POST request with JSON data Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I trying to send a post request with json data in a particular format using Spring boot. I am not getting data in expected format. Please help e resolve it. Thanks in advance.

```
class UserService{
public void sendRequest(User data){
  HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
  mapHeaders.set("Content-Type","application/json");
  Map<String,User> m= new HashMap<String,User>();
  m.put("request",data);
  //print m i.e. payload being sent
  HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(m, header);
  String url = some url here
  ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, httpMethod, entity, 
   Object.class);
   }
}

class User{
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

}
```

While printing payload it displays payload as:

```
{request=User(firstName=Raj,lastName=Kumar)}
```

I want the data as

```
{request={firstName=Raj,lastName=Kumar}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSONObject :

```
Map<String, JSONObject> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put("request", new JSONObject(data));
```

Result :

```
{request={"firstName":"Raj","lastName":"Kumar"}}
```

Maven dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20210307</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you! I directly passed payload as type Object in map and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Do as below using Jackson library in case you need to print an object in JSON format:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

    ...
    m.put("request", data);
            ObjectMapper objectMapper =  new ObjectMapper();
            try {
                String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(m);
                System.out.println(jsonString);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    ...
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for replying. Actually I don't want the payload in the form of a string. I want it as JSON only.

Comment: @mamadgiaishwarya  Output printed in above code snipped will be like "{"request":{"firstName":"Raj","lastName":"Kumar"}}", which is in JSON format